# Equation of current with inductive load

Tags: circuit-analysis, passive-networks

What will be equation of current for the following circuit. Switch is closed at t=0. All the elements are ideal.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFT5Ug.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

**EDIT:**
My approach ,
$$ i(t) = \frac{V_s}{L}\int dt = \frac{V_s}{L} t + K$$
Let at t=0, i(t)=0
$$i(t) = \frac{V_s t}{L}$$
But from a RL circuit equation of current is 
$$i(t) = \frac{E}{R}(1-e^{-(R/L)t})$$
on putting R=0 I get i(t) =  infinity

Comment: Show us your working so far.

Comment: Edited the question

Comment: No for R=0 you get 0/0

Comment: In the second case, what is R/L? What is R/L * t? And what is the exponential of that value?

Comment: L/R is the time constant for an RL circuit and inductor charges exponentially.

Comment: Now, do you know how to evaluate a limit that is of indeterminate form 0/0?

Comment: One can apply L'Hospital, but i'm getting E/L which is independent of t?

Comment: Okay, I got it. previously I was differentiating w.r.t. 't' instead of 'R'.

Comment: If you take the derivatives and let R go to zero you would get: E*(t/V)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

V = L di/dt so, for a given value of voltage and a given inductance value, current rises linearly (di/dt) at a value of V/L.

If V = 1 volt and L = 1 henry then current rises at 1 amp per second.

Comment: Are you happy with this answer?

Comment: Are you unhappy with this answer?